# The extra space problem for Chinese with `gq` command in VIM

Tags: vim, format, cjk

The following is a Chinese paragraph, just forget the meaning of Chinese.

[image]

The following is the chinese paragraph after call `gq` command. Notice that there appear some extra spaces, for example `灵 活性` and `实际上 某种`. In Chinese,  we don't need such extra spaces.

[image]

The following is some setting in my `.vimrc`

```
set ts=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
set ruler
set showcmd
set number
set nrformats=
set textwidth=80
set nocompatible
set formatoptions+=m
```

So what kind of setting can solve this extra spaces problem? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help fo-table`:

> B: When joining lines, don't insert a space between two multi-byte characters.  Overruled by the 'M' flag.

Thus,

```
set formatoptions+=mB
```